# Navigating through data

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I've got a problem. I have to navigate through a file full of parameters (around 40.000) and change a small number of specific parameters.

I've already found a method that kinda works, I'm scanning the file for unique lines which correspont to the values I want to change, and put the position of the line in a list. The lines I want to change are always the same distance from those unique lines.

This works great if I'm only changing lines (while maybe not elegant or fast), but the next step would putting more lines into the file (I have the possibility to put in one constant value, or a list with a bunch of different values).

My solution would be that I start putting those lists in from the end of the file to the beginning (because I don't lose any relative position I still have to change) or to add an offset to every position if i add a list corresponding to the length of the list.

So, are there any more elegant/efficent solutions for it?

Disclaimer: I may be new to python and used to c/c++, so I'm probably thinking far too c/c++ like

Edit:

The code i use to find the lines i need:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ref_lines = []
lines = []
offset = 4

input_data = open("Input.txt", "r")
data = input_data.readlines()
input_data.close()

pos = 1
while pos < len(value_flow_left_p1) + 1:
    counter = 1
    num = "Unique_Reference{}\n".format(pos)
    for line in data:
        if num == line:
            break
        counter +=1
    ref_lines.append(counter - 1)
    pos += 1

for lines in ref_lines:
    counter = lines + 1
    num = "Start_of_Data_after_Reference\n"
    while counter < len(data) - 1:
        if data[counter] == num:
            lines.append(counter + offset)
            break
        counter += 1
```

(I know, technically i could search the relevant lines the same way I search for the "Start_of_Data_after_Reference", but "Start_of_Data_after_Reference" can only have two different names, while the data i want to change has a dozen different names)

Edit 2:
Current:
Input:

```
Unique_Reference1
Dummy 1
Dummy 2
Start_of_Data_after_Reference
Dummy 3
Dummy 4
Dummy 5
Value I want to change
Dummy 6
```

Output:

```
Unique_Reference1
Dummy 1
Dummy 2
Start_of_Data_after_Reference
Dummy 3
Dummy 4
Dummy 5
Changed Value
Dummy 6
```

New:

Input:

```
Unique_Reference1
Dummy 1
Dummy 2
Start_of_Data_after_Reference
Dummy 3
Dummy 4
Dummy 5
Array I want to change:
    1
    2
Dummy 6
```

Output:

```
Unique_Reference1
Dummy 1
Dummy 2
Start_of_Data_after_Reference
Dummy 3
Dummy 4
Dummy 5
New Array:
    new Number 1
    new Number 2
    new Number 3
    new Number 4    
Dummy 6
```

And something like this for about 30 times in this 40.000 line file.

Comment: you have to use python?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @Tamar, yes i have to use python, because all the in corp libraries are for python.

Comment: @s_vishnu, I didn't add code, beause my question is more about concepts than actually implementing it. if you think code is totally necessary I'll add parts of my code, but tbh. it will look disgusting...

Comment: Adding code shows *you tried*. No matter how disgusting you think it is..trust me it's better than nothing.

Comment: Can you show some sample input and desired output?

Comment: @s_vishnu updated.